# Windows gvim - use unix grep

Tags: windows, vim, grep, gvim

Using Windows 10. I have gvim installed. I also have git, and I have git's bin in my PATH (C:\program files (x86)\Git\bin), which puts git's gnu grep in my path so I can use it in the command shell.

```
> grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.4.2
```

However, when I use grep from vim -

```
:grep -ir 'something' .
```

It is using FINDSTR in windows, which doesn't work very well.

How do I make gvim use the GNU grep?  I tried pre-pending the git bin dir to my vim path but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried the [grep.vim : Grep search tools integration with Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=311) plugin?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. that may be the answer, but I'd like to just try getting the grep command use gnu grep rather than an uppercase Grep command.

Comment: You could always install Cygwin ;)

Comment: Did you read `:help grepprg`?

Comment: @romainl - wow I'll have to set aside half a day to do that ;) one of the longest docs I've seen. Looks like it's probably the answer though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external executable for `:grep` is controlled by the `'grepprg'` option, and on Windows, this defaults to `findstr`, as `:help 'grepprg'` details:

> For Win32, the default is "findstr /n" if "findstr.exe" can be found,
>     otherwise it's "grep -n".

So, just put the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set grepprg=grep\ -nH
```

Comment: The backslash escapes the space character; this is necessary for `:set`.